# How can I read the complete documents inside a collection

Tags: python, arangodb, python-arango

I am using the libary [`python-arango`](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/python-arango). Is there an option to read inside a `Collection` e.g. `students` the complete documents?
My aim is that I can see the complete documents inside a dataframe, e.g. `import pandas as pd; df=pd.json_normalize(result['...']['...'])`.

```py
from arango import ArangoClient

# Initialize the ArangoDB client.
client = ArangoClient()

# Connect to database as  user.
db = client.db(<db>, username=<username>, password=<password>)

print(db.collections())
students = db.collection('students')
print(students)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this into to a list:

```py
students = list(db.collection('students'))
```